# Sort dataframe according to a column first and then according to another column in r

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like the following

```
foo <- read.table(text="1 VA
  1 PE
  1 CE
  4 PE
  3 PE
  3 CE
  2 PE")
```

Now I want to sort the data frame according to first row first, which I can do by simply

```
foo[order(foo$V1),]
```

which gives the result :

```
   V1 V2
 1  1 VA
 2  1 PE
 3  1 CE
 7  2 PE
 5  3 PE
 6  3 CE
 4  4 PE
```

But my problem now is I want to keeping the sorted result in V1 same, I want to sort it according to second column. The results should look something like

```
   V1 V2
 1  1 CE
 2  1 PE
 3  1 VA
 7  2 PE
 5  3 CE
 6  3 PE
 4  4 PE
```

where first column is as it is but second column, V2 is also sorted something similar to

```
sort -k1 -k2
```

in unix

Comment: I suggest reading through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29331287/559784) for a fast and memory efficient data.table solution. `setorder()` works with `data.frames` too from v1.9.5+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the package `dplyr`  with `arrange` like

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(foo, V1,V2) # sort according to V1 first, then V2
  V1 V2
1  1 CE
2  1 PE
3  1 VA
4  2 PE
5  3 CE
6  3 PE
7  4 PE
```